# Is my Windows 10 infected with malware?

Tags: malware, virus, windows-10

When i use google chrome occasionally appears about 5 different McAfee's notification (I don't have McAfee installed), one of those:

[image]

ATTENTION! Your computer is in danger. We detected a virus on your computer. You need to remove viruses from your computer. The system is infected. Click here to clean 22.39 uelihaldiscret.online. Open. X Remove propagant.

[image]

"Application Erro. The instruction in 0x00007FFC3C0241C1 retained the memory in 0x0000000000000000, The memory cannot be read.  Click 'OK' to end the program. OK."

What i supposed to do? When I click to close, opens two sites: http://lp3.clean-pc-now.club/ and antivirushub.co but my avast add-ons blocks these sites.

Answer (score 1):

Don't install anything. Windows 10 uses Defender antivirus, if you have not deactivated it. This message comes very probably from some bloatware that you have installed with some other software. If you follow recommendation in the message, you will very probably install virus.

What should you do?

Check what software you have recently installed and remove everything that you don't remember you have installed.

Find a CD or DVD or a (read only) USB stick with antivirus, reboot computer and start this disk with antivirus, launch antivirus and check your computer.

Comment: I will remove my last downloads and run a USB stick with a antivirus. Thanks, let me see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

The first notification does not come from McAfee antivirus nor from a virus, either, but from Google Chrome. This usually means you have allowed a site (this time `uelih.aldiscret.online`) to show notifications, and malicious sites may do this constantly. To control these notifications you can use Google Chrome Help: [Turn notifications on or off](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3220216).

The second error is a bit more alerting. If you are lucky, `RtkAudUService64.exe` is just Realtek Audio Universal Service gone bad and could be fixed by reinstalling/updating the Realtek audio driver. But some malware is also disguised as `RtkAudUService64.exe`. If you have clicked something on the first notification and the problem started after that, the latter is more likely. Did you install or run somethings?

I would start by:

1. Turning the notifications off on Google Chrome.
2. Checking whether the path for `RtkAudUService64.exe` is `C:\Windows\System32\` or something else.
3. Validating the signatures of the `RtkAudUService64.exe` to see whether it is really from Realtek.
4. Sending the `RtkAudUService64.exe` to [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/).

If there is anything suspicious with steps 2-4 or if the notifications turn back on on themselves, then it is time to *nuke it from orbit* i.e. it is better to reinstall the whole system than try and recover from an infection.

Answer (score -2):

I think you better install licensed antivirus software except for any crack version. make sure to enable the firewall on. and do not install anything you cant verified. if you have any doubt about the unknown software just google and check the vulnerable or not.